# Add logic to Ext.Component initialize Sencha Touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I've an application that need to be multilanguage.
The translations comes from the server and are based on the user that is using the application.
My current approach is to create my own field for everything that is used in the app, and during the initialize, I change what it says to the translated text, based on a given code.
For example, in a button, I create my own button like this:

```
Ext.define('myapp.view.shared.MyButton', {
    extend: 'Ext.Button',
    xtype: 'myappbutton',

    initialize: function () {
        this.callParent();
        this.setText(myapp.util.Helper.getTranslation(this.textCode, this.defaultText));
    }
})
```

Then I change de default button configuration to something like this, where I just change the xtype, remove text, and add textCode and defaultText.

```
{
    xtype: 'myappbutton',
    textCode: 'back',
    defaultText: 'Back',
    ...
}
```

Then I define the text code and the default text. The getTranslation method, inspects in a local storage to get the translation for the code, and return the finding, or the default text sent.

**¡Here is the question!**

Since I've 12 different components (so far), and every component extends in some way from Ext.Component, I want to add my code to the initialize of Ext.Component, in order to apply this piece of code, avoiding this crap of creating a custom control for each different control that I need to give translations.
 Is this possible ?

TIA!
Milton.-

Comment: Your question is lacking a question mark. But I see an inheritance problem. You can't be sure which functions are available and/or required to get a certain component to work multi-lingual. Have you evaluated whether overrides could be better than "custom components"?

Comment: Hi Alexander! Thanks for your answer, I've added the question mark :) Regarding what you mention, Ext.Component has the initialize event, so I want to get that event function, and executes mine at the end. Is basically the same I do in every component, but I want to do it just once. Make sense ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can always try something along the lines

```
Ext.define('MyApp.override.Internationalization',{
    override:'Ext.Component',
    initialize: function () {
        me.callOverridden(arguments);
        // Your code here.
    }
});
```

Comment: Looks nice! I´ve no more controls to create, but will try later anyway, so I can remove the custom controls for maintainability. Thanks Alexander!

Comment: Hi Alexander! I've tryied and didn't work. Do you know if this change impacts in all the components with no need to extend from it ? I mean, no need to create components that extends from Internationalization. Make sense ?

Comment: You "override" the `Ext.Component`, which means that the original `Ext.Component` has a changed `initialize` function, which calls the original `initialize` function in `this.callOverridden`.

Comment: You should check whether the file is loaded. You have to add `MyApp.override.Internationalization` to the `requires` list in your `app.js` file for it to load.

Comment: Thanks Alexander! Will try!